# azure mpeg-dash streaming using video.js palayer

Tags: javascript, video.js, azure-media-services, dash.js

I have used microsoft azure media services for video uploading.Video is successfully uploaded and get the streaming url
  http://app_name.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/0c6e02c5-0a78-457f-9528-21d347f8d784/1495798035_video.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)
and trying to play using video.js with scripts dash.all.js and videojs-contrib-dash script (videojs-dash.js)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.19.2/video-js.css">
<video id=example-video width=600 height=300 class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls></video>
 <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.19.2/video.js"></script>
 <!-- Dash.js -->
 <script src="http://cdn.dashjs.org/latest/dash.all.min.js"></script>

 <!-- videojs-contrib-dash script -->
 <script src="videojs-dash.js"></script>

 <script>
 var player = videojs('example-video');

 player.ready(function() {
   player.src({
     src: 'http://trailersbook.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/0c6e02c5-0a78-457f-9528-21d347f8d784/1495798035_video.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)',
     type: 'application/dash+xml'
   });

   player.play();
 });
</script>
```

it is not playing on video but perfectly working on azuremediaplay.I don't want to use azuremediaplayer.
show error

```
 [15][debug] Playback initiated! 
 dash.all.js:11 [1966][parser] Parsing complete: ( xml2json: 4ms,                
 objectiron: 10ms, total: 0.014s) 
 dash.all.js:11 [1968][manifestUpdater] Manifest has been refreshed at 
 Thu Jun 08 2017 10:16:13 GMT+0530 (IST)[1496897173595]  
 index.html:1 Not allowed to load local resource: blob:null/ca125920-
 a5a8-4a2b-b66e-8924ee7c9e03
 dash.all.js:11 [2242][streamController] Video Element Error: 
 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED 
 index.html:1 Not allowed to load local resource: 
 blob:https://portal.azure.com/dda3601f-db19-4039-9edc-e5215e938fbc
 dash.all.js:11 [390979][streamController] Video Element Error: 
 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

Comment: What is `videojs-dash.js`?

Comment: library for providing support for dash in video.js https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-dash

Comment: Interesting. The linked demonstration video plays http://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-dash/, though request is for an `.mp4` file. Try using "https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js" as URL to get `video.js`. Have you filed an issue at github repository?